# C# card shuffle in card deck 52 cards

Tags: c#, image, class, for-loop, picturebox

there is a project for Windows application that I'm still working on and is about a set of card deck. The application utilizes 52 cards which consist of 4 suits and 13 face values such as 2 of Clubs, Jack of Hearts, and so forth. The part that I'm working is that I also have to use five pictureboxes to display each random card so I click on a "Deal" button. I'm aware that I would have to use a "Random" keyword along with using a for-loop to do the shuffle. 
Therefore, I'm not too sure how would I display each picturebox with different random cards and display each card's name accordingly.

Beneath of this contain screenshots of what the windows application looks like and my code for the project.

```
    List<PlayingCard> cardDeckList = new List<PlayingCard>();

    private void buttonDeal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int integer = 0;
        Random picRandom = new Random();
        int n = 0;

        integer = picRandom.Next(0, imageListCards.Images.Count);

        for( n = 0; n < cardDeckList.Count; n++)
        {
            pictureBox_Card1.Image = cardDeckList[integer].CardImage;
            pictureBox_Card2.Image = cardDeckList[integer].CardImage;
            pictureBox_Card3.Image = cardDeckList[integer].CardImage;
            pictureBox_Card4.Image = cardDeckList[integer].CardImage;
            pictureBox_Card5.Image = cardDeckList[integer].CardImage;

        }

        listBoxOutput.Items.Add(cardDeckList[integer].ToString());

    }


    private void FormShuffleCardDeck_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            string[] suitList = { "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades" };

            string[] faceList = new string[13];


            List<int> pointValues = new List<int>();

            pointValues.Add(2);
            pointValues.Add(3);
            pointValues.Add(4);
            pointValues.Add(5);
            pointValues.Add(6);
            pointValues.Add(7);
            pointValues.Add(8);
            pointValues.Add(9);
            pointValues.Add(10);
            pointValues.Add(10);
            pointValues.Add(11);

            string suit = "";
            string face = "";
            int counter = 0;
            int i = 0;
            int k = 0;

            for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                suit = i.ToString();

                switch (suit)
                {
                    case "0":
                        suit = "Clubs";
                        break;

                    case "1":
                        suit = "Diamonds";
                        break;

                    case "2":
                        suit = "Hearts";
                        break;

                    case "3":
                        suit = "Spades";
                        break;
                }

                for (k = 0; k < 13; k++)
                {
                    face = k.ToString();

                    switch (k)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            face = "2";
                            break;

                        case 1:
                            face = "3";
                            break;

                        case 2:
                            face = "4";
                            break;

                        case 3:
                            face = "5";
                            break;

                        case 4:
                            face = "6";
                            break;

                        case 5:
                            face = "7";
                            break;

                        case 6:
                            face = "8";
                            break;

                        case 7:
                            face = "9";
                            break;

                        case 8:
                            face = "10";
                            break;

                        case 9:
                            face = "Ace";
                            break;

                        case 10:
                            face = "King";
                            break;

                        case 11:
                            face = "Jack";
                            break;

                        case 12:
                            face = "Queen";
                            break;
                    }


                    cardDeckList.Add(new PlayingCard(suit, face, imageListCards.Images[counter],2));
                    counter++;
                }


            }

            //for (int l = 0; l < cardDeckList.Count; l++)
            //{
            //    listBoxOutput.Items.Add(cardDeckList[l].ToString());
            //    //MessageBox.Show(cardDeckList.Count.ToString());              

            //}

        }



        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

[Windows App Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40Evf.jpg)

Comment: The shuffle should be in the only thing in the shuffle method. Likewise, only creating the cards should exist in the create deck method. Once this separation is maintained it's as easy as searching for "shuffle cards" on SO and adjusting the code. Both methods should be a good bit smaller than the shown code. In addition, the creation code can be greatly simplified by giving each card in a suite a value 1(ace)..13(king). The card itself knows it's "face value string". Then a simple loop and modulus can be used to create the cards.

Comment: It would be much easier to shuffle the array itself rather than try and pick randomly from an unshuffled deck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how your `PlayingCard` class is coded, but it seems like a large portion of your problems stem from its design. Take this implementation for example:

### `PlayingCard` Class

```
public class PlayingCard : IComparable<PlayingCard>
{
    private int value;
    private int suit;
    private Bitmap cardImage;

    public int Value => value;
    public string ValueName => ValueToName(value);

    public int Suit => suit;
    public string SuitName => SuitToName(suit);

    public Bitmap CardImage => cardImage;

    public PlayingCard(int value, int suit, Bitmap cardImage)
    {
        this.value = value;
        this.suit = suit;
        this.cardImage = cardImage;
    }

    private string ValueToName(int n)
    {
        switch (n)
        {
            case 0:
                return "Ace";
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
            case 5:
            case 6:
            case 7:
            case 8:
            case 9:
                return (n+1).ToString();
            case 10:
                return "Jack";
            case 11:
                return "Queen";
            case 12:
                return "King";
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("Unrecognized card value.");

        }
    }

    private string SuitToName(int s)
    {
        switch (s)
        {
            case 0:
                return "Clubs";
            case 1:
                return "Diamonds";
            case 2:
                return "Spades";
            case 3:
                return "Hearts";
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("Unrecognized card suit");
        }
    }

    public int CompareTo(PlayingCard other)
    {
        int result = this.Suit.CompareTo(other.Suit);

        if (result != 0)
            return result;

        return this.Value.CompareTo(other.Value);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0} of {1}", ValueName, SuitName);
    }
}
```

It has all the comparison and value conversion coded within it, so you don't have to worry about creating highly specialized methods to do extraneous conversions. You can use it in a deck like so:

### Array Implementation

```
// How to initialize deck
PlayingCard[] deck = Enumerable.Range(0, 52)
                        .Select(x => new PlayingCard(x % 13, x / 13, imageListCards[x]))
                        .ToArray();


// How to shuffle deck
Random r = new Random();
Array.Sort(deck, (a, b) => r.Next(0, 2) == 0 ? -1 : 1);

// How to reset deck
Array.Sort(deck);

// How to display top five cards
pictureBox_Card1.Image = deck[0].CardImage;
pictureBox_Card2.Image = deck[1].CardImage;
pictureBox_Card3.Image = deck[2].CardImage;
pictureBox_Card4.Image = deck[3].CardImage;
pictureBox_Card5.Image = deck[4].CardImage;
```

### List Implementation

```
// How to initialize deck
List<PlayingCard> deck = Enumerable.Range(0, 52)
                        .Select(x => new PlayingCard(x % 13, x / 13, imageListCards[x]))
                        .ToList();


// How to shuffle deck
Random r = new Random();
deck.Sort((a, b) => r.Next(0, 2) == 0 ? -1 : 1);

// How to reset deck
deck.Sort();

// How to display top five cards
pictureBox_Card1.Image = deck[0].CardImage;
pictureBox_Card2.Image = deck[1].CardImage;
pictureBox_Card3.Image = deck[2].CardImage;
pictureBox_Card4.Image = deck[3].CardImage;
pictureBox_Card5.Image = deck[4].CardImage;
```

**EDIT:**

### Manual Shuffling

If you want to do a shuffle manually, there's a simple algorithm called the [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](https://www.dotnetperls.com/fisher-yates-shuffle) that will do the trick:

```
private static Random r = new Random();
static void Shuffle<T>(T[] array)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        int idx = r.Next(i, array.Length);
        T temp = array[idx];
        array[idx] = array[i];
        array[i] = temp;
    }
}
```

(List Implementation)

```
private static Random r = new Random();
static void Shuffle<T>(List<T> list)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        int idx = r.Next(i, list.Count);
        T temp = list[idx];
        list[idx] = list[i];
        list[i] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah... I see. This does somehow make sense. Yes, I do use a class called "PlayingCard" and most of the code does involve using from it. I apologize as I'm not that familiar in shuffling cards and displaying each random card through five different pictureboxes. Furthermore, I have a question in mind in shuffling the deck. Is it possible that instead I can shuffle the deck through a for-loop?

Comment: @LasknaK It's certainly possible. See my edit on how to do it.

Comment: Ohh... I see... I tried to search across and understand how the shuffle process would work especially in cards. Thank you. Hmm.. However, how would this work in implementing a list class?

Comment: @LasknaK By replacing array references with `List` equivalents.

Comment: I see. I tried doing that actually... but... it seems that there is an error(a red swiggly mark underneath) for temp... Somehow, the error message indicated that it cannot convert int to PlayingCard...                             for (int i = 0; i < cardDeckList.Count; i++)
            //{
            //    int idx = picRandom.Next(i, cardDeckList.Count);
            //    int temp = Convert.ToInt32(cardDeckList[idx]);
            //    cardDeckList[idx] = cardDeckList[i];
            //    cardDeckList[i] = temp;
            //}

Comment: @LasknaK You are getting an error because you *can't* convert from T to int, which is what you're trying to do with `Convert.ToInt32`. There are no conversions necessary, or even a change to the logic. All you need to do is take stuff that's specific to arrays (like the `T[]` notation, for example) and convert it to the list equivalent (i.e. `List<T>`). See edit.

Comment: OH... I see... I'm sorry that I have to continue to ask due to limited knowledge in C#. Therefore, to actually use this shuffle method, I would have to store it in a variable and use it to display in each picturebox?

Comment: @LasknaK The shuffle method just takes an array/list and shuffles it. The cards themselves remain unaffected, so you can still use the `deck[0].CardImage;` example that I gave above.

Comment: I see. Thank  you @Abion47. It actually works. After following though, I was able to make it work and display each card's image along with adding the corresponding card's image's name.

Comment: @LasknaK If it works, make sure to mark this as your answer.