# How to sort a string array with integers and strings in?

Tags: c#

I have a string array:
string[] face = {"A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K" };

I randomized it and now I am trying to sort it back to what it was.
I tried the Array.Sort() method but it didn't work.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41095545/c-sharp-card-shuffle-in-card-deck-52-cards) for sorting cards

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: What do you consider to be the proper order? Should letters come first, or numbers? You need to tell us what you need to be able to help you

Comment: @Kobus edit your question

Comment: The Batman, to answer your question: I need it to start from "A" first and follow all the way to "K"

Comment: Okay, so this is a playing card problem then. You should specify that in your question.

Comment: @Kobus can you add the expected result please

Comment: You should use a custom IComparer to set the priority of the cards. On this thread you can read a useful implementation: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/223593/deck-of-cards-with-shuffle-and-sort-functionality

Answer (score 0):

You could use LINQs `OrderBy` method

```cs
var ordered = random.OrderBy(face => CardValue(face)).ToArray();
```

with the following `CardValue` method

```cs
int CardValue(string card)
{

    switch(card)
    {
        case "A":
            return 1;
        case "J":
            return 11;
        case "Q":
            return 12;
        case "K":
            return 13;
        default:
            return int.Parse(card);
    }
}
```

just to give you a gist of how this could be achieved. This sample is not really production-ready, though.